# MySQL syntax error in python but working in MySQL shell

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am using MySQLdb in python

I have a table let table1 with 4 fields one is index which is PRIMARY KEY and suppose others are field2, field3, field4. Since field2 is not unique, I have many rows with same value for this field.
Now when I query select field3,field4 from table1 where field2=example, I get a MySQL syntax error near 's'. This 's' belongs to 'select'.

To debug it I printed the query in runtime and pasted it in MySQL shell where it returned all the rows matching the where clause.

Here is my actual python code

```
query = "select `field3`,`field4` from `" + atable + "` where `field2` = '"+avalue+"'"
cur.execute(query)
temp = cur.fetchall()



 Error:
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove backticks

```
query = "select field3,field4 from " + atable + " where field2 = %s"
cur.execute(query, (avalue,))
temp = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: Didn't work...
but yes the error is changed.
Syntax error shifted to last part

Comment: @SudhanshuMishra, What are the values of `atable`, `avalue`?

Comment: This one is working

    query = "select `field3`,`field4` from `" + atable + "` where `field2` = %s" % avalue

Comment: @SudhanshuMishra, `"... %s" % avalue` is not good idea. It is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @falsetru `execute` params should be a tuple, not a list. Like this: `cur.execute(query, (avalue,))`

Answer (score 0):

falsetru's solution is almost correct  - however there is one little problem with the SQL query:

The original query and the related code is as shown below:

```
query = "select field3,field4 from " + atable + " where field2 = %s"
cur.execute(query, (avalue,))
temp = cur.fetchall()
```

Note the past part of the where clause. Here you have **%s** as a string hence the correct way to write the SQL would be:

```
query = "select field3,field4 from " + atable + " where field2 = '%s'"
```

Note that **%s** has been enclosed within single quotes (**'**) character.

Comment: You don't need to enclose the %s with single quotes, MySQLdb takes care of it. @falsetru 's solution is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the note - I was looking at it from a pure SQL perspective and did not know about this tiny tidbit. Thank you once again :)